# Thousands separator with razor MVC and js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, digit-separator

I'm trying to save number with thousands separator inside number field

1000 >> 1,000

100000 >> 10,000

2000.02 >> 2,000.02

i want to use js and jquery for this issue,
i want thousands separators become visible when the user is typing.

```html
<div class="form-group">

  <label class="control-label col-md-2" Sum</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sum, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number" } }) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [autoNumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) plugin. Basic init will do what you need:

```
$('#Sum').autoNumeric('init');
```

Check section:

> The basics on getting `autoNumeric()` up and running with the initialize
>   'init' method and default settings: ...

Comment: How i can find latest version of AutoNumeric? I'm trying to find it, but i can't. do you have another link? @teo

Comment: @askm on this page we have **Compatible with jQuery-1.7.2 and higher.** so what's problem?

Comment: @askm, you can find it here : https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/